# Adding progressbar to pop up kv language

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to add `ProgressBar` to `PopUp` using the kv language.
As per the docs I have to pass the `ProgressBar` to it as `content`.

But it gives error.

```
<DownPop>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Downloading'
    content:
        ProgressBar:
            value: 50
            max: 100
    Button:
        text: 'Click me to dismiss'
        on_press: root.dismiss()
```

Error Traceback:

```
 ...
      62:    content:
      63:        ProgressBar:
 >>   64:            value: 50
      65:            max: 100
      66:    Button:
 ...
 Invalid indentation (too many levels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that's not going to happen. `content` is mainly for python side if I'm right.

It's used for `add_widget(content)` in `__init__()` of a widget, because it needs to be placed somewhere inside the widget e.g. Popup is built with Label, Button, some strip etc + blank space in the center, which is reserver for `content` and from that content it's added in init. Content is basically a placeholder for whatever you want to add to widget that uses that attribute.

Inside kv you can simply add a new widget as you are used to:

```
<DownPop>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Downloading'
    ProgressBar:
        value: 50
        max: 100
```

But there are limits for some widgets, because in some only *one* widget is allowed. Then it basically tells you to use a layout i.e. like this:

```
<DownPop>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Downloading'
    BoxLayout:
        ProgressBar:
            value: 50
            max: 100
        ManyOtherWidgets
```